# Why am I getting an AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute 'draw_bullet' error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to follow along in the Python Crash Course book and create the Alien Invasion game.  I've noticed that there are a bit of issues with this book but have yet to find a good answer to the issue I am having.  I've gotten pretty far in the development but I am currently stuck on this AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute 'draw_bullet' error, after adding in the play button.  (For reference, this is roughly page 296 of the 7th edition book)  Here is the error message.  I'm a bit confused as the bullet attribute shouldn't be in the Alien object, but I am too new to understand where my wires are getting crossed.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

[Callback error message]

[image: 1]

alien_invasion.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from button import Button
from ship import Ship
from alien import Alien
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    
    # Make the Play Button.
    play_button = Button(ai_settings, screen, "Play")
    
    #Create an instance to store game statistics.
    stats = GameStats(ai_settings)
    
    # Make a ship, a group of bullets, and a group of aliens.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()
    
    # Create the fleet of aliens.
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    
    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, bullets)
        
        if stats.game_active:
            ship.update()
            gf.update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
            gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
            
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stats, ship, aliens, bullets, play_button)
        
        
run_game()
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys
from time import sleep

import pygame

from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()
        
def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Fire a bullet if limit is not reached."""
    # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)                 
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            check_play_button(stats, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y)

def check_play_button(stats, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y):
    """Start a new game when the player clicks Play."""
    if play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
        stats.game_active = True
                        
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stats, ship, aliens, bullets, play_button):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # Redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
        
    ship.blitme()
    aliens.draw(screen)
    
    # Draw the play button if the game is inactive.
    if not stats.game_active:
        play_button.draw_button()
        
    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
    # Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()
    
    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
    
    check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
    
def check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Respond to bullet-alien collisions."""
    # Remove any bullets and aliens that have collided.
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)        
    if len(aliens) ==0:
        #Destroy existing bullets and create new fleet.
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
        
def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    """Determine the number of aliens that fit in a row."""
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    """Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit on the screen."""
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows
    
def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    """Create an alien and place it in the row."""
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)
    
def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    """Create a full fleet of aliens."""
    # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)    
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, alien.rect.height)
    
    # Create the first row of aliens.
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)
            
    
def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
    """Respond appropriately if any aliens have reached an edge."""
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
            break
            
def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens):
    """Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction."""
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
    ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1

def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Respond to ship being hit by alien."""
    if stats.ships_left > 0:
        # Decrement ships_left.
        stats.ships_left -= 1
    
    else:
        stats.game_active = False
    
    # Empty the list o faliens and bullets.
    aliens.empty()
    bullets.empty()
    
    # Create a new fleet and center the ship.
    create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
    ship.center_ship()
    
    # Pause.
    sleep(0.5)
    
    

def check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen."""
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
            # Treat this the same as if ship gets hit.
            ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
            break
    
def update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Check if the fleet is at an edge, and update positions of all aliens in fleet."""
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()
    
    # Look for alien-ship collisions.
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, aliens):
        ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
        print("Ship hit!!!")

    # Look for aliens hitting the bottom of the screen.
    check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
```

alien.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the alien and its starting position."""
        super(Alien, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        
        # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        
        # Store the alien's exact position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        
    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the alien at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    
    def check_edges(self):
        """Return true if alien is at edge of screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True
        
    def update(self):
        """Move the alien right of left."""
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor * self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from the ship."""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        
        # Create a bullet rect at (0,0) and then set correct position.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        
        # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor
        
    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet up the screen."""
        # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        #Update the rect position.
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the screen."""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Comment: The PROBLEM is that you have somehow added an `Alien` object to the list of bullets being passed to `update_screen`.  That list needs to contain only bullets.  There's too much code here, so you'll have to add some debug prints to figure out where that is happening.

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course. This is from the first edition of the book, which is pretty out of date at this point. The game project in the second edition is entirely class-based, which avoids this issue of keeping track of so many arguments. Here's the [project](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/tree/master/chapter_14/adding_play_button) at this point in the second edition.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  All in all the book is pretty good when it comes to learning, as I feel I've come a long way since "Hello World!".  I had found the book in a second hand book store and decided to dive in, not realizing the age of the text.  Would you say that the same out of date issue applies to the data visualization section?

Comment: The data visualization chapters are a series of smaller projects. So you can try them and drop it when you get to a point where the code doesn't work. But I suggest you do not try the Django project from the first edition, that is definitely out of date at this point.

Answer (score 0):

the `create_fleet` function signature in game_function is :

```
def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
```

while in `run_game()` you are passing bullets instead of alien as arg, so this should fix it :

```
...
# Create the fleet of aliens.
gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens) #last parametr should be aliens
```

Comment: This fixed it!  Thank you!  I had been searching for hours on that and didn't understand what was going on.